# What's the correct format for MAKEFLAGS when using Fish shell?

Tags: shell, compiling, make, fish

To improve compile times, the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Makepkg#Improving_compile_times) states,

> Users with multi-core/multi-processor systems can specify the number
> of jobs to run simultaneously. This can be accomplished with the use
> of `nproc` to determine the number of available processors, e.g.
> `MAKEFLAGS="-j$(nproc)"`.

If I set this in Fish shell via `set -Ux MAKEFLAGS "-J$(nproc)"`, then I receive the error:

```
fish: $(...) is not supported. In fish, please use '(nproc)'.
set -Ux MAKEFLAGS "-J$(nproc)"
                     ^
```

I can set this variable in two ways without receiving an error:

1. `set -Ux MAKEFLAGS "-J(nproc)"`
2. `set -Ux MAKEFLAGS '-J$(nproc)'`

Which of these is the correct method? Or are they both okay?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither. In fish, command substitution cannot be quoted.

```bsh
set arg "-J(nproc)"
set -S arg
```

```
$arg: set in global scope, unexported, with 1 elements
$arg[1]: |-J(nproc)|
```

Use

```bsh
set -Ux MAKEFLAGS "-J"(nproc)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of fish 3.4.0, command substitutions can be quoted using the `"$()"` syntax, so the original command works now.